# why HoverBehavior in kivymd work in further distance of the considered widget?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to make an application. I start with the menu and I am designing the clickable items.

I try to make a hover behavior and I made it. but when I run the program the hover behavior effects above the widget and it has a lot of distance(if you move your curser to the its above mdlabel(تنظیمات اصلی) it effects and the color will change)
but I want hoverbehavior to effect at the specified position widget.
what should I do?
try to focus more on Nav_card class because this class has to have the hoverbehavior.

```
### Importations

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import StringProperty , ObjectProperty , ListProperty , OptionProperty

import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivymd.toast import toast
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import HoverBehavior , MagicBehavior
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior


Builder.load_file("j.kv")


class WidgetsManager(MDScreenManager):
    current_heroes = ["hero"]


class Nav_card(MDCard , ThemableBehavior , HoverBehavior , MagicBehavior):
    click_nav_bg = OptionProperty([0.67,0.84,0.90 , 1] , options=[[0 , 0 , 0.54 , 1] , [0.67,0.84,0.90 , 1]])
    icon_name = StringProperty("blank")
    right_text = StringProperty(" ")
    left_text = StringProperty(" ")
    icon_on_release = ObjectProperty(None)
    ripple_duration_in_fast = 1
    ripple_duration_out = 1
    hovering = True
    hover_visible = True
    magic_speed = 3




class MainApp(MDApp):
    click_nav_bg = OptionProperty([0.67,0.84,0.90 , 1] , options=[[0 , 0 , 0.54 , 1] , [0.67,0.84,0.90 , 1]])
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.theme_cls.theme_style_switch_animation = True
        self.theme_cls.theme_style_switch_animation_duration = .7
    def change_style(self , button , nav_drawer):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light" if self.theme_cls.theme_style == "Dark" else "Dark"
        button.icon = "weather-sunny" if button.icon == "moon-waning-crescent" else "moon-waning-crescent"
        nav_drawer.md_bg_color =  [0 , 0 , 0.54 , 1] if self.theme_cls.theme_style == "Dark" else [0.67,0.84,0.90 , 1]
        self.click_nav_bg =  [0.67,0.84,0.90 , 1] if self.theme_cls.theme_style == "Light" else [0 , 0 , 0.54 , 1]
        Nav_card().click_nav_bg = [0.67,0.84,0.90 , 1] if self.theme_cls.theme_style == "Light" else [0 , 0 , 0.54 , 1]


    def change_hero(self , interval):
        self.root.current = "screen B"
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.theme_cls.material_style = "M3"
        return WidgetsManager()
    def farsi_font(self , text:str):
        reshapedValue = get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(text=text))
        return reshapedValue
    def on_start(self):
        toast(font_size=35 , text= self.farsi_font("به این برنامه ریاضی خوش آمدید") , duration=7 , font_name="C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\kivymd\\project\\B-NAZANIN.TTF")
        Clock.schedule_once(self.change_hero , 7)

MainApp().run()
```